# Proving that the sum of the errors of a least square linear approximation is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$ be points in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $e=[\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n]^T$ the error vectors belonging to the least square solution of the linear approximation. Prove that $\epsilon_1+\dots+\epsilon_n=0$.

I honestly don't have the slightest of clues on how I should approach this excercise. I know that $A^TA\bar{x}=A^Tb$ gives the least squares solution in general, but that is about as far as I get. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The error vector, $e$, is, by definition, $Ax-b$, and you know $A^te=0$. But one of the rows of $A^t$ is all ones.